# How to restrict an xs:choice containing xs:any?

Tags: xsd

If I have a xs:complexType that conatins this:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
   <xs:any/>
</xs:choice>
```

I understand that xs:any meany any *valid* element, but normally, I wouldn't want my root element to be used anywhere except as root, so can I prevent that by saying 'any *except* the root (or any other specific) element' ?

Answer (score 2):

I think an ideal solution would be to refactor the schema so that you have one type that does not include `<xs:any/>` and another one with it `<xs:any/>`, that is if you really have to use if for some reason.
In general `<xs:any/>` is a very strong statement that throws the validation out of the window as it pretty much allows anything from any namespace, having said that what you're probably after here is `processContents="strict" or processContents="lax"` attribute, so:

```
<xsd:any processContents="strict"/>
```

means that for any namespace it will have to validate against a schema, even if the schema doesn't exists
or (probably better for your case):

This will only require validation if the schema exists.

Because you are defining a schema for your own namespace, this will work - ie if you try to use a root element from your own/default namspace - it will validate it against that namespace and tell you it's not allowed.

You can refer to the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#any) for more details.